# No data received in PHP file via Angular POST method

Tags: php, angular, post

since few day's I've been struggling to find solution to my problem with POST request using Angular to which I'm quite new.
To the point. I have authentication service in which I have login method like on attached picture.
[Auth service.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqtdT.png)

Everything works fine until I change the name of php backend file to which I POST data, from wynik.php to anythingelse.php. If I rename **the same file** (also change file name inside POST request) to auth.php or dog.php it stops working throwing error code 400 ( which is inside php file for no data inside login and password fields).
Php screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rz4g.png)
And logs form request:
[LOG 1,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PifGr.png)   [LOG 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJyoY.png).

Seems like no data is received after file rename.

**.htaccess** for XAMPP

```
RewriteEngine On
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://localhost:4200

Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"

Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, 

Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding"

Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
```

Any help welcome.

Comment: You can include code directly in the post and do not have to link to external screenshots.  That said, if everything works until you change the file name it sounds like you have a discrepancy between the new file location and what your Angular code things the new file location should be. Are you using the angular dev server with a proxy? Maybe you need to check the proxy config. Are you accessing the PHP server directly?  You may need to check your CORS settings on the server.

Comment: I'm using XAMPP for Apache and MySQL. Renamed file is in the same folder. I will also include .htaccess in my post.